# Apache CXF 2.0.12 to 2.2.7 upgrade issue

Tags: java, jetty, cxf

I have upgraded a CXF web service implementation from Apache CXF 2.0.12 to 2.2.7 and now I can't connect from a remote computer.

```
http://localhost:9000/Data?wsdl
```

works on the installed computer.

```
http://computername:9000/Data?wsdl
```

from a remote computer does not work anymore (worked before upgrade).

The service is configured in code (no configuration files) with the following code:

```
DataServiceImpl dataImplementor = new DataServiceImpl();
JaxWsServerFactoryBean svrFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
svrFactory.setServiceClass(DataServiceImpl.class);
svrFactory.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/Data");
svrFactory.setServiceBean(dataImplementor);
if(intercept) {
  svrFactory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
  svrFactory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
}
svrFactory.create();
```

Is there anything in the configuration which defines "Allowed clients" or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was binding Jetty to `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0` which resulted in not being able to access the web service from a remote computer (since only the loopback adapter was bound).

This is probably a change in the Jetty version used by CXF.